# How can i save data from notifications GCM into sqlite 3 for android?

Tags: android, sqlite, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

i try to save data into sqlite from notifications and doesn't save anything, i appreciate the help, sorry for my English :P

This is my code:

```
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("New todo item!")
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("message"));

    String message = (String) intent.getExtras().getCharSequence("message");
    String ju = "ja";
    String jo = "je";
    message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    HandlerSQL db = new HandlerSQL(this);
    db.abrir();
    db.insertMsg(message,ju,jo);
    db.cerrar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all replace this line

```
String message = (String) intent.getExtras().getCharSequence("message");
```

with this line

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

Since you don't need the first one, and then place the following lines of code before calling the notification and in `onMessage()` received method in your `GCMIntentService()`

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message"); 
String ju = "ja";
String jo = "je";
HandlerSQL db = new HandlerSQL(this);
db.abrir();
db.insertMsg(message,ju,jo);
db.cerrar();
```

and finally make sure that  `db.insertMsg(message,ju,jo);` is valid method that going to insert the strings in SQLlite Database.